# Infinite scroll return multiple results in IE

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I created a simple infinite scrolling for my website which shows more images when scrolling at the bottom. It works great with Chrome but when I test it on Internet Explorer the loader shows results multiple times. I don't know where is the error.

Here is my jQuery code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e){

    $(document).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() ==    $(document).height()){
            var pictureCount = $(".Picture-1A").length;
            $.get('ajax/home-pagination.php', {off_set:pictureCount}, function(data){
                $("#homeContent").append(data);
            });
        }
    });

});
```

I send the off_set to the php page which will return the data with the new pictures and append it to the end of the page

Comment: Which version of IE are you using, tested on 10 and works fine.

Comment: have you echo'd the offset you get in the PHP so you can see the return.

Comment: @PatrickLC When I put alert before append content when scrolling i get more than one alert, this is why it's repeating the output. I am using IE 10

Comment: @CayceK Yes I have. and when I use alert I get multiple alerts when scrolling down

Comment: In this case it would be wiser to use console.log so that you can get a more accurate representation of the offset. Alert is delayed depending how quickly you scroll.

Comment: @CayceK The script works fine with Chrome but not with IE. I am using IE 10

Comment: I'm sorry I am not sure what else it could be... The only thing I could try that doesn't seem like it would work would be change the `==` to `>=` esp since @PatrickLC states it works fine in 10.

Comment: @CayceK I have figured out the problem. When IE goes to the bottom it alerts more than one time. The problem is with the value pictureCount. In Internet explorer the value get assigned more than once. This is why it return more than one Ajax call. How can I fix this?

Comment: @CayceK here is the page I am testing: [link](http://www.picturepunches.com/testing/)

Comment: I think it has to do with something stupid with IE... I would say change it from checking the bottom to checking 50pxs from the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

this should work:

first implement the cdn of debounce to your page

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-throttle-debounce/1.1/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js"></script>
```

then

in your scroll function, add the debounce function like this:

```
$(window).scroll($.debounce(100, function(){ /* function */ }));
```

Hope this works for you too. :)